# youtube embed video show "Video Unavailable"

Tags: php, html, video, youtube, embed

I use the youtube iframe embed code from youtube share button and i get this code

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wjIuBh09WGU" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have run it in webpage and thumbnail is loaded also the spinner loading and then it get an error "Video unavailable"

Screenshot:

[image: Video Unavailable]

Comment: how is this php related?

Comment: what you posted won't cause that. You're not giving us the details here. Again; how it this php related? You tagged as such.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

YouTube does this if you load your HTML file in a browser directly from disk (C:). Upload it to a server and it will work.

Comment: can you explain how to do it exactly?

Comment: I only get this error for a few, eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EzdmE4Ewqk
how can I filter out failing videos from search result?

Comment: While this might be true for localhost, you can still get this behavior if your server is remote. Opening the video mentioned in the question still shows a "Video Unavailable" message.